# Get item references

Tags: podio, xero-api

Using **get item references** returns just a few fields of the app item. If I then use **Get item by app_item_id** to drill down to all of the fields.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this so that I can just use one call instead of multiple calls to get the details of a referenced object? At the moment, the plan is to repeat the same calls for each of the referenced items.

Use case is that I have an 'Invoice' item in Podio, with one or more referenced 'Inventory' items. I am using this data to push those items through to Xero as seperate line items.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please bundle responses (that's super powerful technique to reduce number of requests). You can read more about bundling responses here: https://developers.podio.com/index/api (scroll page down)

**Ruby** example

```
item_id = <some item id>
item = Podio::Item.find(item_id, {'fields' => 'refs'})
puts item['refs']
```